# Firebase error: "Authentification key is not active"

Tags: firebase

Prior a week from today, I had code that was working fine on Firebase Cloud Functions.

I've tried numerous solution to debug the problem but have run into this wall every time my code is activated:

```
{"errors":[{"code":20,"message":"Authentification key is not active"}
{"code":21,"message":"No permission for this authentication key"}]}
```

One solution had changed this error code into another:

```
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","errors":[{"message":"Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 818729994826 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.","domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","extendedHelp":"https://console.developers.google.com"}],"status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"}}
```

Which leads me to believe that this is authenticated related even though the code is hosted in a Google domain which I assume should be automatically authenticated.

Comment: You API Key is wrong it seems.  Where is this set?

Comment: Don't think I set up a API key at all.I follow Google Document on Cloud functions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started and it didn't specify any API key input as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found the source of my error and the log response is not from Google but from my own code.

I am working in a team and it is without my knowing that one of my member of my team made some changes (unfortunately this is the environment I am working on so no git or mention what changes is happening).

Procedures to come to this conclusion is akin to disabling one plug-in at a time in Wordpress.

I broke my code apart in pieces and ran them and they ran perfectly fine. Until I came across a code that was talking to api and therefore spitting out this error.

Hope that helps anyone going through some big unknown in error debugging. Also, probably a nice caveat to learn unit testing.